# Getting error while generating n random numbers in a range

Tags: python

When I run the code I get error :
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

The error comes in the line where I allot random numbers to list listOfNews

```
    def createUserData(self):
        max_in=max(self.newsIdData,key=int)
        min_in=min(self.newsIdData,key=int)
        #print(self.newsIdData)
        for userId in range(5):
            noOfMovie=randrange(10)
            listOfNews=[random.randint(min_in, max_in) for i in range(noOfMovie)]
            self.userData[userId]=listOfNews
            print(self.userData)
```

Comment: Please post the whole stack trace. Also you should create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: check the types of `max_in` and `min_in`, are they strings or ints? If `self.newsIdData` contains strings then max will return a string regardless of your key.

Answer (score 0):

You should check which line of code that is generating this error and then try to cast the relevant `int` as a string.

For example, let's assume that `listOfNews` needs to be an iterable of strings, in this case you should change your list comprehension as follow:

```
listOfNews=[str(random.randint(min_in, max_in)) for i in range(noOfMovie)]
```